# Commerce Orders dropdown text

Tags: sitecore-commerce

On the Orders dashboard, we can see orders filter dropdown. I have been trying to find out where the text (Display name) for orders filters dropdown is defined, but not able to. 
[image]

Sitecore 9.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text for these are defined in Sitecore.

Expand the below item in Sitecore:

/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Commerce Engine Settings/Commerce Terms/BusinessTools/ViewActionNames

[image]

You will see a long list of commerce terms.
Here name of Sitecore Item is key and Value field on the Commerce Term item is the text (Display Name).

To get the list of keys used in the filter dropdown do following:

1. Goto folder "{Commerce-Authoring-Root}\wwwroot\data\Environments".
2. Open file "PlugIn.Habitat.CommerceAuthoring-1.0.0.json".
3. Search for "KnownOrderListsPolicy".
4. In this policy you can see a property "KnownOrderListsPolicy" and that has key defined for each value.

Use keys to search the respective item in Sitecore item mentioned above.

You might need to refresh cache in commerce engine to see the changes.